# Would this situation be a ratio of 1/5 or 1/10?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Hypothetical situation that I'm trying to use for understanding some criminal statistics.

Let's say there is a city with 10 banks.

One criminal robs two banks before being arrested and placed in jail.

Would the probability of having a bank robbed be 1/5 (2 robberies / 10 banks) or 1/10 (1 criminal / 10 banks)?

**Why I'm asking:**

The data I'm looking at contains the identities for criminals and I'm trying to understand some way of measuring the impact of crime in the community.

I'm thinking that when counting the frequency of crimes, one person committing more than one crime wouldn't necessarily be indicative of a crime wave.

Comment: Suppose one really successful criminal gets around and not only robs every bank, but robs some of the them again.  Other criminals may commit robberies, too, over some (perhaps long) period of time, leading (say) to 50 robberies of 10 banks. What sense would you make of the assertion that "the probability of having a bank robbed is 5 = 50/10"?

Comment: @whuber lol - okay, given the scenario, my head is spinning. I don't can't think of a way to make sense of that. It sounds like the count of criminals outweighs the count of crimes.

Comment: Just the opposite: many criminals commit multiple crimes and--by definition--the count of crimes cannot be any less than the count of criminals! What's missing here is any sense of what you are trying to accomplish with your use of statistics. Also missing is any information about how numbers of criminals, banks, or robberies could be (quantitatively) related to "impact of crime in the community."

Comment: Since I have the hometown of criminals in the records, I thought it would be interesting to list the most frequent type of crime by town. But in doing that, I wasn't sure if I should start by counting the crimes or the criminals. I then wanted to see the ratio of the crime or the criminal compared to the population of the town.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you start with a simple stochastic process, explore it thoroughly, and then expand it to cover the full set of cases.

For example, you could start with a stochastic process that assumes that each criminal can only rob one bank per day.  Each day, each of the criminals chooses to rob a bank or not (a Bernoulli trial). If they choose to rob a bank that day, they then choose a bank to rob (with uniform probability). Given a decision to rob and a choice of bank, the criminal has a probability of success (getting money and not getting arrested) vs. failure (not getting money or getting arrested).  But probability of success may not weigh into crime statistics.

The probability of any given bank being robbed on any given day is a function of the total number of criminals and the probability that they will, individually, choose to rob on any given day and that they will select a given bank on that day.

Related but somewhat separate is the probability of being arrested. Each day there is a probability that each criminal might be arrested, conditional on the number of robbery attempts (successful or not).  Presumably, the higher numbers of robbery attempts increases the probability of being arrested.

With this model, you need to estimate the total population of criminals (i.e. potential bank robbers), the daily probability that each criminal would choose to rob a bank, and the conditional probability of being arrested given a number of robbery attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If the robber randomly selects two different banks, the probability for each bank to be robbed is 2/10=0.2 .

(Consider an extremal case: the robber robs all 10 banks.  The probability is 1.)

If he randomly selects a bank, then again randomly selects a bank (not neccessarily a different one), the probability for each bank to be robbed is $ 1-0.9^2=0.19 $